# d3: my code will create 1 chart but not 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'd like to call my d3 code several times and have the output show up in different places on my site. I placed the code in a function (`chart`) and I'm trying to call it twice and pass it different arguments.

http://jsfiddle.net/5rk6g234/

I'm getting a strange `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` error in my d3 code.
The code runs fine if I only call the function once, but as soon as I do:

```
chart(dj, "#c"); //dj is my data, #c is the div where I want the chart
chart(dj, "#e"); //dj is my data, #e is the div where I want the chart
```

It throws this error and won't make the second chart. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not actually sure why this didn't work. I looked around and I don't see any issues with using the same data to create two graphs. However, if you copy the data to a separate `variable` the graphs will run without error: http://jsfiddle.net/5rk6g234/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This chunk of code, which lives inside `chart()`:

```
data.forEach(function(d){
    d.d_string = parseDate(d.d_string);
    d.c_string = +d.c_string;
  });
```

The first time it runs, it does what you'd expect; it converts `d.d_string` into a `Date` object. The 2nd time though, `d.d_string` is already a Date, and d3's date parser expects only a String, so it errors out.

It works fine if you move that block outside of `chart` (and rename `data` to `dj`):

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
dj.forEach(function(d){
  d.d_string = parseDate(d.d_string);
  d.c_string = +d.c_string;
});
```

[The modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5rk6g234/3/)